# URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher - how to convert received value to string?

Tags: ios, swift, string, csv, combine

Being a Swift newbie I am trying to download and parse a CSV file using the code:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .tryMap(handleOutput)
    .sink { completion in
    } receiveValue: { csvWords in

        let lines = csvWords.split(separator: "\n")
        for line in lines {
            let columns = line.split(separator: ",")
            for column in columns {
                print("column: \(column)")
            }
        }
```

however I get the syntax error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data.Element' (aka 'UInt8')

[image: Xcode]

Please help me to understand, what is happening.

What value is returned by the [receiveValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/sink(receivevalue:)), isn't it the remote file content as string?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the missing method

```
func handleOutput(output: URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output) throws -> Data {
    guard
        // as? means "this might be nil"
        let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        response.statusCode >= 200,
        response.statusCode < 300
        else {
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
    
    return output.data
}
```

Comment: Show `handleOutput`.  Otherwise how do we know what csvWords is??? But no, what comes from the network is a Data until you convert it to a String.

Comment: Ok, I have added `handleOutput` to my question, apologies for missing out

Comment: Yup, there you go. You return `return output.data`. That's a Data. So that is what passes down the pipeline into the sink.

Comment: Should I change to `return output.data as? String` then?

Comment: There is no "should". Personally I would just do exactly what Robs answer advises: add a compact map operator. Anyway what you are doing here is way overloading the sink; the sink shouldn't do processing, just receiving.

Comment: Who should do the processing then, a `map()`?

Comment: Yes! That's how I would do it. But a lot depends on what values you want to produce at the end of the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your error message, `handleOutput` would appear to be publishing `Data`. If you want to call string functions, you would map that to `String`, e.g.,

```swift
var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

func foo(_ url: URL) {
    cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryMap(handleOutput)
        .compactMap { String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8) }
        .sink { completion in
            ...
        } receiveValue: { string in
            ...
        }
}
```

Or, if you want, you could throw an error if it can't be converted to a string:

```swift
var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

func foo(_ url: URL) {
    cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryMap(handleOutput)
        .tryMap { data -> String in
            guard let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
            }
            return string
        }
        .sink { completion in
            ...
        } receiveValue: { string in
            ...
        }
}
```

---

In your revised question, you shared `handleOutput`. You could simply change that to produce your `String` for you:

```swift
func handleOutput(output: URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output) throws -> String {
    guard
        let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        200 ..< 300 ~= response.statusCode,
        let string = String(data: output.data, encoding: .utf8)
    else {
        throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
    }

    return string
}
```

And then you don't need that extra `compactMap`/`tryMap`:

```swift
func foo(_ url: URL) {
    cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryMap(handleOutput)
        .sink { completion in
            ...
        } receiveValue: { string in
            ...
        }
}
```